# Run VBA Macro after changing date in datepicker Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following issue: I'm using a datepicker in Excel. The datapicker is linked to a cell, let's say A1. I want to run a macro when I pick a different date (and cell A1 is changed). I know that I can run a macro when cell A1 is *manual* changed, but in this case the cell is changed by the datepicker. So in short: How can I run a macro based on a value in a cell which can change dynamically?

The code I have so far (where A1 is the selected date in the datepicker):

```
Private Sub DTPicker1_CallbackKeyDown(ByVal KeyCode As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal CallbackField As String, CallbackDate As Date)

End Sub
```

---

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Target.Worksheet.Range("A1")) Is Nothing Then Call Macro
End Sub
```

Comment: How is the value in `A1` getting update? Is it another macro/UDF that updates `A1` or a formula?

Comment: It's updated by a datepicker/calendar. So in the calender I select for example 27-11-2019 and then in cell A1 changes to the value 27-11-2019.

Comment: It's not selection_change, it's supposed to be `Worksheet_change`

Comment: I still have to select the cell and press enter for the macro to run unfortunatelly.

Comment: I think you need to add a Change event for your datepicker, rather than Worksheet cell A1 (I'm pretty sure this won't respond to any of the Worksheet events).

Comment: Use `DTPicker1_Change()`

Comment: When you click the date on the datePicker, the code in the datepicker should make A1 = datepicker, then worksheet_change event will kick in.

Answer (score 0):

To run a macro when the value in Datepicker is changed you have to add event listener on your datepicker. Example with *DTPicker1* and *B1* value:

```
Private Sub DTPicker1_CloseUp()
    Range("B1").Value = DTPicker1.Value
End Sub
```

More infos: